# Convert HTML2PDF and base64 images

Tags: java, pdf, itext

My html content is like below:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <B>This is bold text</B><BR/>
    <img style="width:91px;" align="middle" alt="mylogo" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, {base_64_data}"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

And i have a simple conversion code:

```
OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("dest.pdf"));
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
document.open();
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, is);
...
```

When i run it, it generates dest.pdf file that contains bold text. But there is not an image in pdf file.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Yes, when i open html file with browser, it displays image

Comment: Same problem. Is there anybody with a solution?